# redirect STDERR in tcsh from .aliases

Tags: tcsh

in tcsh I'm trying to redirect STDERR from a command from my .aliases file.

I found that I can redirect STDERR from the command line like this. . .

```
$ (xemacs > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```

. . . but when I put this in my .aliases file I get an alias loop. . .

```
$ cat .aliases
alias xemacs '(xemacs > /dev/tty ) >& /dev/null'
$ xemacs &
Alias loop.
$
```

. . . so I put a backslash before the command in .aliases, which allows the command to run. . .

```
$ cat .aliases
alias xemacs '(\xemacs > /dev/tty ) >& /dev/null'
$ xemacs &
[1] 17295
$
```

. . . but now I can't give the command any arguments:

```
$ xemacs foo.txt &
Badly placed ()'s.
[1]    Done                          ( \xemacs > /dev/tty ) >& /dev/null
$
```

Can anyone offer any solutions?  Thank you in advance!

---

UPDATE: I'm still curious if it's possible to redirect STDERR in tcsh from .aliases, but as has been suggested here, I ended up with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# wrapper script to suppress messages sent to STDERR on launch
# from the command line.
/usr/bin/xemacs "$@" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is a case where NOT using an alias is the best option - try using a shell script instead:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

(xemacs $* > /dev/tty ) >& /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
alias emacs '(\emacs \!* > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null'
```

The "badly placed ()'s" message comes from misplacing the input parameter to emacs.  Without the "`\!*`" in the alias definition, "`emacs abc`" becomes

```
(/usr/bin/emacs > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null abc
```

With the "`\!*`" included, "`emacs abc`" becomes

```
(/usr/bin/emacs abc > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```